# How do I convert a S3M file to MP3?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, mp3

I tried to use `ffmpeg` to convert this S3M file http://modarchive.org/index.php?request=view_player&query=34641 into MP3, but it plays incorrectly. It sounds like the music is coming from the basement. VLC won't play it correctly either. ModPlug won't play it correctly either. I've only found that the JavaScript player plays it correctly, but it doesn't seem to generate a file that can be saved.

Answer (score 1):

It plays properly with [OpenMPT](https://openmpt.org/). You have several choices of how to use it:

- The stable release on the [download page](https://openmpt.org/download) is a GUI program for Windows users for playback and converting.
- There is a multi-platform cli tool: [`openmpt123`](https://lib.openmpt.org/) for playback and converting.
- [Plugins](https://lib.openmpt.org/) are available for various players: Winamp, XMPlay, Kodi, foobar2000, Audacious, qmmp, etc.
- Compile `ffmpeg` with `--enable-libopenmpt`.

Comment: Neat. Is there a Chocolatey package for it? https://chocolatey.org/packages

Comment: @Chloe [Yes](https://chocolatey.org/packages/openmpt), but slightly outdated. I've never heard of Chocolatey until you mentioned it...I'm not really a Windows user.

Answer (score 0):

Plays fine in Potplayer and [AIMP](http://www.aimp.ru/index.php). FFmpeg & VLC both use Modplug as demuxer, so the culprit here is Modplug, possibly its incomplete support for preamp.

I suggest using the Convertor included with AIMP.