# How can I convert .xm, .mod, and others to .mp3 using avconv?

Tags: ffmpeg, music, libav

I recently downloaded a pack of keygen chiptunes (via http://keygenmusic.net/), and most of them are in file formats such as .xm, .mod, etc. I'd like to convert them all to mp3, hopefully using a tool like avconv (so I can batch process them).

However, when I issue `avprobe <filename>`, I get the following error:

```
avprobe version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
2000AD/2000AD - Creatures To The Rescue +3 trn.mod: Invalid data found when processing input
# avprobe output
```

How can I convert these files to mp3 format?

Also, here is a list of all the filetypes I need to convert:

```
   24 ahx
    2 amd
    4 bp
    7 d00
    4 fc13
   15 fc14
    6 hsc
  217 it
   99 mid
    5 mo3
  989 mod
    6 mp3
    1 mtm
    3 nsf
   19 ogg
    3 rad
   82 s3m
    2 S3M
  119 sc68
   18 sid
  124 v2m
    9 wav
 3116 xm
   20 ym
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `ffmpeg`. It has support for the external libraries [libopenmpt](https://lib.openmpt.org/libopenmpt/), or the older libmodplug, which are needed for module files. You'll need to get or compile `ffmpeg` with `--enable-libopenmpt` or `--enable-libmodplug`.

`avconv` is missing this capability, among many other things.

Also see [How do I convert a S3M file to MP3?](https://superuser.com/a/1087383/110524)

Comment: I compiled ffmpeg with `--enable-libmodplug` and now I can convert `it, mod s3m, xm` to `mp3`. For some reason I cannot convert mp3 to any of those formats. When I try "ffmpeg -i file.mp3 file.mod" I get the error *"Unable to find a suitable output format for file.mod"*

Comment: @sergio These external libraries are demuxers only and do not enable encoding of these formats. FFmpeg does not have support for encoding of module and tracker files.

Comment: Saving a MOD/XM/S3M/IT as MP3 is the equivalent of saving a Photoshop PSD as a JPEG. MP3 and JPEG is the "merged" format - can't be converted back to the complex format that PSD and MOD/XM/S3M/IT is.